# PHP - Redirect based on country

Tags: php

I am looking to make a universal link which redirects a user based on their country. I have looked at MaxMind but am looking for something free and simple.

Is there any way of detecting the user country with at least 80% accuracy without using a third party?

Comment: Find all IP addresses of available countries, add them to your own table and make requests.

Comment: I know you said no third party, this is 3rd party, but it is simple and free. http://api.wipmania.com/<add the ip address here>.

Comment: Are you using CloudFlare for your site? If that is the case, you can access the CloudFlare header: `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` Otherwise, you would need to have a copy of IP->Country relations, tho these are subject to change (?)

IMO, if you have a copy of this, then the fastest way to match would be using a match of the range: `192.168.1.0/24` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement your own ! You have to make a tables of country wise IP addresses ...

Or Simply you can use the following plugin.

If you want to implement a redirect using GeoPlugin (Third Party)

**Here is the GeoPlugin config.php file**

```
<?php

class geoPlugin {

    //the geoPlugin server
    var $host = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={IP}&base_currency={CURRENCY}';

    //the default base currency
    var $currency = 'USD';

    //initiate the geoPlugin vars
    var $ip = null;
    var $city = null;
    var $region = null;
    var $areaCode = null;
    var $dmaCode = null;
    var $countryCode = null;
    var $countryName = null;
    var $continentCode = null;
    var $latitude = null;
    var $longitude = null;
    var $currencyCode = null;
    var $currencySymbol = null;
    var $currencyConverter = null;

    function geoPlugin() {

    }

    function locate($ip = null) {

        global $_SERVER;

        if ( is_null( $ip ) ) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        $host = str_replace( '{IP}', $ip, $this->host );
        $host = str_replace( '{CURRENCY}', $this->currency, $host );

        $data = array();

        $response = $this->fetch($host);

        $data = unserialize($response);

        //set the geoPlugin vars
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->city = $data['geoplugin_city'];
        $this->region = $data['geoplugin_region'];
        $this->areaCode = $data['geoplugin_areaCode'];
        $this->dmaCode = $data['geoplugin_dmaCode'];
        $this->countryCode = $data['geoplugin_countryCode'];
        $this->countryName = $data['geoplugin_countryName'];
        $this->continentCode = $data['geoplugin_continentCode'];
        $this->latitude = $data['geoplugin_latitude'];
        $this->longitude = $data['geoplugin_longitude'];
        $this->currencyCode = $data['geoplugin_currencyCode'];
        $this->currencySymbol = $data['geoplugin_currencySymbol'];
        $this->currencyConverter = $data['geoplugin_currencyConverter'];

    }

    function fetch($host) {

        if ( function_exists('curl_init') ) {

            //use cURL to fetch data
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'geoPlugin PHP Class v1.0');
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

        } else if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {

            //fall back to fopen()
            $response = file_get_contents($host, 'r');

        } else {

            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Error: Cannot retrieve data. Either compile PHP with cURL support or enable allow_url_fopen in php.ini ', E_USER_ERROR);
            return;

        }

        return $response;
    }

    function convert($amount, $float=2, $symbol=true) {

        //easily convert amounts to geolocated currency.
        if ( !is_numeric($this->currencyConverter) || $this->currencyConverter == 0 ) {
            trigger_error('geoPlugin class Notice: currencyConverter has no value.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return $amount;
        }
        if ( !is_numeric($amount) ) {
            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Warning: The amount passed to geoPlugin::convert is not numeric.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return $amount;
        }
        if ( $symbol === true ) {
            return $this->currencySymbol . round( ($amount * $this->currencyConverter), $float );
        } else {
            return round( ($amount * $this->currencyConverter), $float );
        }
    }

    function nearby($radius=10, $limit=null) {

        if ( !is_numeric($this->latitude) || !is_numeric($this->longitude) ) {
            trigger_error ('geoPlugin class Warning: Incorrect latitude or longitude values.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return array( array() );
        }

        $host = "http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/nearby.gp?lat=" . $this->latitude . "&long=" . $this->longitude . "&radius={$radius}";

        if ( is_numeric($limit) )
            $host .= "&limit={$limit}";

        return unserialize( $this->fetch($host) );

    }


}

?>
```

And Here is the code to Validate country.

```
require_once('config.php'); //The above code
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "OM") {
header('Location: https:www.something.com/ae');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "US") {
header('Location: https://www.something.com/en');
}
}
```

If you are not sure about your country code [Check Here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with CloudFlare. First you need to get a CloudFlare account setup on your domain, and have IP Geolocation enabled. This will put a Country Code in the CF-IPCountry header. Then you could use a php switch statement for redirects.

```
switch($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]) {
  case: "US"
    header("Location: http://example.com/US");
  case: "UK"
    header("Location: http://example.com/UK");
}
```

Relying on a third party such as CloudFlare is most likely your best bet, as CloudFlare won't be going out of business anytime soon, and CloudFlare handles updating the list with new IPs. If you really don't want to use a third party, you can always replace the `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` with a different country code detector.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at cloudflare. Any idea of how accurate their geolocation is?

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with their geolocation, but I know for IPv4 it's pretty robust, but I'm not sure about IPv6. From my experience with CloudFlare, I would imagine they will have IPv6 pretty robust too soon.